How to prevent auth.js skipping next.js middlware
I'm trying to implement Auth.js into my Nextjs project, I followed the step guide https://authjs.dev/getting-started/installation and also implemented credentials provider https://authjs.dev/getting-started/authentication/credentials.
The issue is that it skip the middleware.ts file after sign-in. How can I prevent that ?
